# Refreshing List of MIDI Input Devices

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using pygame's MIDI module to collect a list of available MIDI input devices.

I'm using a method inside a custom-built class to generate this list like so:

```
def create_devices(self):
        pygame.midi.init()
        devices = []
        device_count = pygame.midi.get_count()
        for d in range(device_count):
            device = pygame.midi.get_device_info(d)
            device_name = device[1].decode()
            device_type = device[2]
            if device_type == 1:
                input_device = MidiDevice(d, device_name)
                devices.append(input_device)
        return devices
```

I'm setting the list returned from this method to a property in my class in the constructor, and later on I'm rendering the inputs to the screen as buttons meant for selection.

I also have a refresh button that when clicked executes this function and sets the property in my class to the list returned again.

The problem I'm running into is that even if I add or remove MIDI inputs while the program is running, the refresh button always returns what was originally created in the class constructor.

Restarting the program after changing my inputs ends up displaying the inputs that are presently available.

I'd like for the refresh button to automatically find the new inputs, but I must be missing something.

I'm pretty new to pygame and python in general, so I'm eager to learn why this is behaving counter to how I expect.

Any help is super appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED.

Turns out I needed to quit the pygame.midi module so that it could be reinitialized.

Here's the small change that fixed my issue:

```
    def create_devices(self):
        pygame.midi.init()
        devices = []
        device_count = pygame.midi.get_count()
        for d in range(device_count):
            device = pygame.midi.get_device_info(d)
            device_name = device[1].decode()
            device_type = device[2]
            if device_type == 1:
                input_device = MidiDevice(d, device_name)
                devices.append(input_device)
        pygame.midi.quit() # THIS LINE FIXED IT
        return devices
```